# scapy for receiver?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, scapy

I want to make a client-server model where server will send some UDP packet and client will receive them. I am thinking of using Scapy to send packets. Does Scapy gives any facility to receive packets(listen for packets)?

Comment: I've removed the websocket tag as I can't see any relation to it in your question.  If you add the tag back, can you please rephrase your question as well?

Comment: Use the sniff() function. Takes packet counts, function to call when received, as well as filters as arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scapy is able to craft packets, i.e. to build specific packets according to your needs. And yes, [sending and receiving functions](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) are the core functions of scapy. However, This is more for debugging purposes than for production systems. You should consider using Python's `socket` module directly.